# FabricJS with PaperJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, paperjs

I'm studying some ways to integrate PaperJS and FabricJS.

As you can see in the link below, when you click the "Time to Draw!", the red-bordered canvas becomes able to draw, thanks to Paperjs library.

But I want to make the blue canvas drawable.

Inside activatePaper function I have:

```
PaperCV = document.getElementById('ccc');
```

If I change 'ccc' to the blue canvas ID ('myCanvas'), the drawing functionality stops working.

I think it's something about scope.

Could anyone help me?

http://codepen.io/jeanpaulo/pen/wgoaLY

Comment: Please try insert into function cancelCanvas() this code: canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
  canvas.clear();
  it will allow you do freehand drawing using FabriJs

Comment: It kinda worked, but as you said, it allowed me to draw using the Fabric library. I'm trying to enable the PaperJS (because it has a lot of vector funcionalities).